# How to set initial value in form with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, razor

I have a web app written in C#, ASP.NET Core. I am trying to set an initial value, and did this with Node.JS, but when I try it in ASP.NET Core, it returns "null".

```
<input type="hidden" name="Completed" value="Not Started" 
       id="Completed" asp-for="Completed" />
```

To display, I use:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Completed)
</td>
```

Comment: I can guess that it's `item` that is null. Are we also supposed to guess what `item` is? You're setting the value to `item.Completed` and it isn't right. That appears to be the only details needed here. But you omitted them.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared how actually you are assigning the value to `item.completed` it is difficult to say what is causing the said issue.

Below is one example that could help you set the initial value.

**Person.cs (Model class):**

```
namespace MVC_Bootstrap.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Homecontroller.cs**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
     TempData["name"] = "Abc";
     return View(new MVC_Bootstrap.Models.Person());
}
```

**index.cshtml**

```
@model MVC_Bootstrap.Models.Person

Set Default Name using TempData :  
@Html.TextBox("Name", @TempData["name"])
```

**Output:**

[image]

If your requirement is a little different then you could share your sample code that could help us reproduce the issue. We could try to provide suggestions for it.